# How to grab a user's mailbox setting using the Graph SDK

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm having trouble trying to obtain this data using the Graph client library found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph in my c# application. I'm aware that the data is available using this [REST API call](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings).

I've created my azure application and provided the application "Read all user mailbox settings" permissions and clicked on "grant permissions" to apply them. The problem is not with my authentication. I'm able to retrieve data.

```
MicrosoftAuthenticationProvider authProvider = 
    new MicrosoftAuthenticationProvider(applicationID, applicationSecret, microsoftURL);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (User user in users)
{
    //user.MailboxSettings
    //returns null, but through intellisense, I can obtain it's attributes
    //Microsoft.Graph.MailboxSettings is available in the library's object browser

    //graphClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].MailboxSettings.Request().GetAsync() 
    //User.MailboxSettings is not available
}
```

As a last resort, I'll use the REST API, but if I can, I want to just use the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just append **Select("MailboxSettings")** to your query.

Get users's MailboxSetting based on your code

```
                IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await 
                    graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

                foreach (User user in users)
                {
                    User fullUser = await graphClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();

                    MailboxSettings mailboxSettings1 = fullUser.MailboxSettings;                     
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! That worked! I'm new to this and didn't realize there was a "Select" function. I was basing this off of the command I had used for messages which was `IUserMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Messages.Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: I need to retrieve the user's timezone. By doing what you specified the timezone property is null as indicated in the image. Can you give me a solution on how to get the timezone property form mailboxsettings ?

Comment: @SoufienHajji  I'm getting the TimeZone information coming through.  Can you check the AdditionalData property? Sometimes when the data is not parsed for some reason, it gets stored in the AdditionaData collection.

Comment: I've found in AdditionalData.ResponseHeaders.Value.ResultsView something named {[Date, [
  "Tue, 13 Nov 2018 08:17:56 GMT"
]]}
Does this represents what should be in the timezone ? or represents the date of the query ?

Comment: Not all mailboxes will have TimeZone filled out, especially if no one has logged into it. I had to account for this.

`User user = await graphClient.Users[id].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();
    if (user.MailboxSettings == null || user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone == null)
     return null;
    else
     return user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone;`